# Using Cin and Argv

Tags: c++, cin, argv

How do I combine cin and argv in a script?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
c == argv[1];
cin >> c;
```

How do you ignore cin if there's a command line argument, or do cin if there's no command line argument?

Comment: `argc` gives you the count of arguments. If it's high enough for `argv[1]`, you can just set it, and input it if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `std::cin` and objects of class `std::ifstream` both share a common base class: `std::istream`. You can use this fact to pass either `cin` or an `ifstream` to a common function:

```
void DoOne(std::istream& in) {
  int x;
  in >> x; // etc etc
}

int main (int ac, char **av) {
  if(ac == 1)
    DoOne(std::cin);
  else {
    for(i = 1; i < ac; ++i) {
      std::ifstream inFile(av[i]);
      DoOne(inFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It's possible that I didn't understand the question.

Comment: You're assuming the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;

if(argc == 2) 
    s = argv[1];
else
    cin >> s;

... do stuff here ...
```